# query must match 2 fields exactly, don't analyze

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried a few different ways of doing a simple get request, filtering on two different attributes, **example**:

```
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "email": "erik.landvall@example.com"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "password": "bb3810356e9b60cf6..."
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "query": {
            "match_all": []
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get nothing back in return. As I understand it, this is because ElasticSearch analyzes the email field, making the query fail. So if I however would use the term `erik.landvall` instead of the complete email address, it will match the document - which confirms that's what's going on.

I can define the attribute as `type:string` and `index:not_analyzed` when I create the index. But what if I wanna be able to search on the email attribute in a different context? So there should, to my mind, be a way to specify that I wanna filter on the actual value of the attribute in a query. I can however not find how such a query would look.

Is it possible to force Elasticsearch to use "`not_analyze`" when querying? If so, then how?

Comment: I don't have a lot of time to answer your question but take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40007971/case-insensitive-elasticsearch-with-uppercase-or-lowercase/40009671#40009671 and I think you will be interested of this as well:  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html - you can specify multiple fields with different mapping for one input json field. If no one will answer your question more deeply I will do it tomorrow.

Comment: @Adam Both of these suggestions seems to address specifying the mapping prior to the query when creating the index. My question is if it's possible to specify this with out changing the index.

Comment: I have never used it but there is a possibility to specify an analyzer on a query level but not all queries allow it. If you don't want to analyze input string then you just need to specify keyword analyzer. You can read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32565662/elastic-search-match-query-with-analyzer-is-not-working or take a look here (analyzer field in a query): https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html

Comment: @Adam I got a few answers here, none that fits my needs though. But I haven't given up yet. I tried the `keyword` analyzer, but it doesn't match on the email field at all, my take on it is that the field is already analyzed when persisted, and when querying, there is no `@` symbol to compare with.
Did some tests with the `zero_terms_query`. So far it seems to do what I need, but not sure how it will handle if there is 2 emails in the same field for instance. The `keyword` analyzer seems to be what I wanted to use, but something is messing it up for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html) for this purpose. You would have to directly access the JSON you have stored with [_source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_source_field). Try following query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
                "inline" : "_source.email==param1 && _source.password==param2",
                "params" : {
                    "param1" : "erik.landvall@example.com",
                    "param2" : "bb3810356e9b60cf6"
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You would need to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting). Add `script.inline: on` to your yml file and restart the node.

If this kind of query is fairly regular then It would be much better to reindex the data as others have suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to turn on/off analyzed or not, the way to do it to "transform" your field to analysis you need by [using fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/multi-fields.html).

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my_index?pretty' -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "city": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": { 
              "type":  "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/1?pretty' -d'
{
  "city": "New York"
}'
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/2?pretty' -d'
{
  "city": "York"
}'
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index/_search?pretty' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "city": "york" 
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "city.raw": "asc" 
  },
  "aggs": {
    "Cities": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "city.raw" 
      }
    }
  }
```

}'

Comment: this is not possible to be done as default in the yml-settings file? so that `not_analyzed` always is present?

Comment: @ErikLandvall the only way i see is to definy dynamic templates https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html